# Integrating maven project in Android project

Tags: android, maven

I am building an Android application, and I want to use certain functionalities that are supplied in a Maven project.

What is the easiest way to use this maven project in my Android project? I have never worked with Maven so I prefer to deal with it as little as possible.

I tried exporting the maven project into a jar using eclipse and then using it to my android's project build path, but when I run it I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: info.bliki.api.User.

So what would be the easiest way to use this Maven project in my Android project?

Comment: Once you got the jar file created from Maven project, add it as a external jar into Android project's build path **as well as tick it in the build path order and export list**. Or if you use SDK r17+, simply copy the jar file into your Android project libs/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i guess you're just interested in the resulting artifact, then you should be able to just run in the command line (you need to have a version of Maven running though)

```
mvn install
```

which compiles and build the project. You'll get a local copy directly written into ~/.m2/ ... this is where all maven artifacts are installed to . You could then just grab the resulting jar (if it is one) or link directly to the resulting artifact.

Comment: I still get the same exception. What could be the problem? When I run the maven project itself it works just fine.

Comment: It seems like the maven project does link, not include another artifact. You should check the dependencies node in the pom.xml for the next step.