# how to run maven project in android ? or convert maven project to android project?

Tags: android, maven, maven-2, maven-3

i try to upload video to youtube by use this open source
https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/

the problem couse by maven tool ... i never use it , and  dont know how to use it.

**there is way to transform maven project to android project ?**

**if not , so how I could run this maven project on my android device ???** (dont forge that i dont know how to use it)

I also can not copy the project to a new Android project because I can not find all the
jar files.

i try this advice :
 [Integrating maven project in Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861772/integrating-maven-project-in-android-project)

in commend line (when i locate in my app path  ) i type this :

mvn install

look like  : (idan is my app)

```
C:\סינכרון\פרוייקט אפליקציה\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan>  mvn install
```

(`C:\סינכרון\פרוייקט אפליקציה\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan` ) is where the pom file is.

and i recieve those errors :

```
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[24,36] error: package com.google.android.gms.com
    mon does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[57,33] error: package android.support.v4.content
     does not exist

    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[187,6] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[138,4] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[138,43] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[142,57] error: package YouTubePlayer does not
    exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[173,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[176,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[185,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[188,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[191,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[303,20] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[302,14] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[305,17] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[306,10] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[308,17] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[317,17] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[365,12] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[450,12] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[545,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [INFO] 70 errors
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 6.082s
    [INFO] Finished at: Mon May 06 00:44:32 IDT 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/169M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
    3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ytdl: Compilation failure: Compilation
    failure:
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\ResumableUpload.java:[17,34] error: package com.google.android.gms.
    auth does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\ResumableUpload.java:[31,29] error: package android.support.v4.app
    does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\ResumableUpload.java:[32,33] error: package android.support.v4.cont
    ent does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\util\ImageCache.java:[30,30] error: package android.support.v4.util
     does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\util\ImageCache.java:[70,12] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[17,36] error: package com.google.android.
    gms.common does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[18,36] error: package com.google.android.
    gms.common does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[19,34] error: package com.google.android.
    gms.plus does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[20,34] error: package com.google.android.
    gms.plus does not exist
   [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[19,54] error: package com.google.android.youtu
    be.player.YouTubePlayer does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[20,54] error: package com.google.android.youtu
    be.player.YouTubePlayer does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[21,40] error: package com.google.android.youtu
    be.player does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[52,4] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[52,31] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[54,10] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[177,35] error: package YouTubePlayer does not
    exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadService.java:[27,33] error: package android.support.v4.conten
    t does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[17,34] error: package com.google.android.gms.aut
    h does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[18,34] error: package com.google.android.gms.aut
    h does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[19,34] error: package com.google.android.gms.aut
    h does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[20,34] error: package com.google.android.gms.aut
    h does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[21,36] error: package com.google.android.gms.com
    mon does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[22,36] error: package com.google.android.gms.com
    mon does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[23,36] error: package com.google.android.gms.com
    mon does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[24,36] error: package com.google.android.gms.com
    mon does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[57,33] error: package android.support.v4.content
     does not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\ResumableUpload.java:[66,28] error: package NotificationCompat does
     not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\ResumableUpload.java:[66,70] error: package NotificationCompat does
     not exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\ResumableUpload.java:[168,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\ResumableUpload.java:[168,40] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\util\ImageCache.java:[141,31] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[62,30] error: package PlusClient does not
     exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[68,17] error: cannot access XmlPullParser

    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[119,1] error: method does not override or
     implement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[126,1] error: method does not override or
     implement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[130,1] error: method does not override or
     implement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\UploadsListFragment.java:[187,6] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[138,4] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[138,43] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[142,57] error: package YouTubePlayer does not
    exist
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[173,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[176,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[185,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[188,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[191,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[196,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\DirectFragment.java:[199,2] error: method does not override or impl
    ement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[152,4] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[188,6] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[236,26] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[235,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[303,20] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[302,14] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[305,17] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[306,10] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[308,17] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[317,17] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[365,12] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[450,12] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \±Θ≡δ°σ∩\⌠°σΘΘ≈Φ α⌠∞Θ≈÷ΘΣ\SOURCE\YOUTBUE\YOUTUBE FOR UPLOAD\Idan\src\com
    \google\ytdl\MainActivity.java:[545,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
    ch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
    d the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
    eption
```

EDITE : add pom file

MY POM FILE :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.google.ytdl</groupId>
    <name>YouTube Direct Lite App for Android</name>
    <artifactId>ytdl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>google-api-services</id>
            <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <android.version>4.1.1.4</android.version>
        <android.platform>16</android.platform>
        <android.support.version>r13</android.support.version>
        <android-maven.version>3.5.0</android-maven.version>
        <project.youtube.version>v3-rev44-1.13.2-beta</project.youtube.version>
        <project.plus.version>v1-rev64-1.13.2-beta</project.plus.version>
        <project.http.version>1.13.1-beta</project.http.version>
        <project.oauth.version>1.13.1-beta</project.oauth.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
            <version>${project.youtube.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
            <version>${project.plus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.http.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${project.http.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${project.oauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>${project.oauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>gen</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android-maven.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>${android.platform}</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    </configuration>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>

                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.4.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>replace</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android-maven.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>android:android</exclude>
                        <exclude>com.google.android.maps:maps</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <buildOutputDirectory>bin</buildOutputDirectory>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</buildcommand>
                        <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</buildcommand>
                        <buildcommand>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</buildcommand>
                        <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <!-- via this activation the profile is automatically used when the release 
                is done with the maven release plugin -->
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>signing</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <inherited>true</inherited>
                                <configuration>
                                    <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                                    <archiveDirectory />
                                    <keystore>${sign.keystore}</keystore>
                                    <alias>${sign.alias}</alias>
                                    <storepass>${sign.storepass}</storepass>
                                    <keypass>${sign.keypass}</keypass>
                                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- the signed apk then needs to be zipaligned -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${android-maven.version}</version>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <sign>
                                <debug>false</debug>
                            </sign>
                            <zipalign>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk
                                </outputApk>
                            </zipalign>
                            <manifest>
                                <debuggable>false</debuggable>
                            </manifest>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>alignApk</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>zipalign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk</file>
                                    <type>apk</type>
                                    <classifier>signed-aligned</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-signed-aligned</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>17</platform>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>

    <exclusions>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 

  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes , i using eclipse...

Comment: What happens if you right click the project and choose `Maven > Update Snapshots`? Check the maven console to see if it's downloading the dependencies or not.

Comment: i have 'maven > update project' , i dont have 'Maven > Update Snapshots'  after  right click.

Comment: That's it. What happens? do you see any error in maven console?

Comment: just appears those lines in console                                        [2013-05-06 00:20:43 - google-play-services_lib] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-05-06 00:23:01 - google-play-services_lib] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\jarlist.cache

Comment: Apparently these lines were probably earlier, there is no change after maven > update project

Comment: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:proguard (execution: default-proguard, phase: process-classes) pom.xml ‪/YouTube Direct App for Android‬ line 164 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:generate-sources (execution: default-generate-sources, phase: generate-sources) pom.xml‪/YouTube Direct App for Android‬ line 164 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping

Comment: Obviously maven is unable to download dependencies. A plugin bug or something else. I'm pretty sure you will get a good answer here very soon. It's already midnight here. I'll check your issue again tomorrow if nobody has answered you. Sorry again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29471/discussion-between-sam-rad-and-idan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright after long discussion in chat here is the solution. In order to solve this:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle
>   configuration:com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:‌​3.5.0

You should install *Android Configurator for M2E* from Eclipse Market:

> Select Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... and search for `android m2e`.
>   Click the Install button next to the Android Connector for Maven

An then install `Google Play services` from `Android SDK Manager` and add it as an Android Library project to the Eclipse. Set the `ytd-android` project to use this library and:

> Maven -> Update Project
>   Run As -> Android Application